# What is the difference between a Normal and a Gaussian Distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, terminology

Is there a deep difference between a Normal and a Gaussian distribution, I've seen many papers using them without distinction, and I usually also refer to them as the same thing.

However, my PI recently told me that a normal is the specific case of the Gaussian with mean=0 and std=1, which I also heard some time ago in another outlet, what is the consensus on this?

According to Wikipedia, what they call the normal, is the standard normal distribution, while the Normal is a synonym for the Gaussian, but then again, I'm not sure about Wikipedia either.

Thanks

Comment: Wikipedia is right, in this case. It usually is for topics like this. I would be more leery of it on controversial topics.

Comment: There is a consensus.  Your PI is confusing "Normal" with "Standard normal."  The former refers to any version of the latter obtained via a change of location or scale.

Comment: Go with Wikipedia & Peter & whuber - & hire a different private investigator.

Comment: Here's one moderately authoritative reference: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GaussianFunction.html.

Comment: Peter Flom is right - as is Wikipedia, and whuber, and Scortchi. You can find any number of more authoritative works that support it - hundreds, perhaps thousands of standard texts for example and numerous papers.

Comment: As first commenter there, @PeterFlom should probably convert his comment into an answer so this Q. has a good answer.

Comment: I have heard the convention of using "Gaussian" only for the standard normal before (in the context of theoretical CS). This is not standard usage, and indeed is the opposite of what you've apparently heard, so I'd recommend against it. :)

Comment: Shortly: "Standard Normal Distribution" is a particular case of Gaussian(Normal) distribution where Mean_value=0 and Standard_Deviation=1.

Comment: Normal Distribution = Gaussian Distribution. Standard normal Distribution is special case of Normal/Gaussian distribution where mean is 0 and standard deviation is 1. All Standard Normal Distributions are Normal/Gaussian Distributions. But not all Normal/Gaussian Distributions are Standard Normal.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Wikipedia is right. The Gaussian is the same as the normal. Wikipedia can usually be trusted on this sort of question.

Answer (score 2):

In http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalDistribution.html, there is a mention of a standard Normal distribution which looks like the one you were mentioning as mean = 0 and std = 1. But the Normal distribution is the same as Gaussian which can be converted to a standard normal distribution by representing using the variable z = (x-mean)/std.